# How to define enumerate to use letters without indenting?

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

Thus far I used the enumerate-environment with arabic numbers and wrote in my preamble `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*}` to avoid indenting. And it works well.

Now I'm trying to tell enumerate with `\setenumerate[0]{label=(\alph*)}` in my preamble to use small letters instead of arabic numbers. It works but now is a small indent in my list. When i use `\Alph*` instead of `\alph*`, it works without indenting, but I don't want to use big letters.

Is there any way of avoiding the indenting with `\alph`?

PS: I use the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Could you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? It would help identify the problem you're currently experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the width of the label used when the label is `\alph*` is that of the character `m`.  You can change this with the `widest` option:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*} 
\setlist[enumerate,0]{label=(\alph*),widest=a}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally `\setenumerate` is deprecated.